# how to post array through ajax

Tags: php, ajax

hi i try to pass array with ajax code as below i use the following method

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="demo";
$password="";
$db_name="demo"; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select db");
$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
   mysql_query($sSQL);
   $date=date("Y-m-d");

$query="SELECT wp_posts.ID as Id,wp_posts.post_title as Title,wp_posts.post_date as DATE,wp_postmeta.meta_key,wp_postmeta.meta_value,
GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name) AS TAGS, wp_posts.post_content as CONTENT,wp_terms.term_id,wp_terms.slug,wp_terms.name,wp_posts.post_parent as parent_id FROM wp_terms
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id  = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON(wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)
WHERE post_type LIKE 'post' AND post_status LIKE 'publish' and meta_key='source' and post_date like '%2014-11-27%'
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID order by post_date DESC limit 10";

 $query_run=  mysql_query($query);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            $meta_value_id=  "select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key='_thumbnail_id' and post_id='".$row['Id']."'";   
            $query_run_meta=  mysql_query($meta_value_id);
            $row1=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run_meta);

            $meta_image=  "select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key='_wp_attached_file' and post_id='".$row1['meta_value']."'";   
            $query_meta=  mysql_query($meta_image);
            $row2=  mysql_fetch_assoc($query_meta);



            $detail['news_id']=($row['Id']);
            $detail['news_title']=(strip_tags($row['Title']));
            $detail['news_date']=(strip_tags($row['DATE']));
            $detail['news_detail']=(strip_tags($row['CONTENT']));
            $detail['news_category']=(strip_tags($row['slug']));
            $detail['news_name']=(strip_tags($row['name']));
            $detail['news_key']=(strip_tags($row['meta_key']));
            $detail['news_source']=(strip_tags($row['meta_value']));
            if($row2['meta_value']!='')
            {
            $detail['news_image']=("http://demo.alroeya.ae//wp-content/uploads/".$row2['meta_value']);   
            }
            else
            {
               $detail['news_image']="";   
            }

             $details[]=$detail; 
         }

 ?>

<script>
 $(function() {
     var data = '<?php $details?>';

                $.ajax(

                       {

                        url: 'http://nztdemo.com/TestProjects/vault/phpinfo.php',
                         datatype: 'html',

                         type: 'post',
                         data: {str: data} ,

                         success: function(data){
                         alert(data);


                         }
                     });
            });
        </script>
```

and if i print the $details to above php page as i got the result

Array ( [0] => Array ( [news_id] => 126388 [news_title] => رئيس الدولة بخير وعافية وصحته طيبة [news_date] => 2014-11-27 03:17:03 [news_detail] => أكد الفريق أول سمو الشيخ محمد بن زايد آل نهيان ولي عهد أبوظبي نائب القائد الأعلى للقوات المسلحة، أن ما تداولته مواقع التواصل الاجتماعي من أنباء حول صحة صاحب السمو الشيخ خليفة بن زايد آل نهيان رئيس الدولة، حفظه الله، أخيراً، عار عن الصحة، ولا تعدو أن تكون إشاعات متناقلة. وجزم بأن صاحب السمو رئيس الدولة، حفظه الله، بخير وعافية وصحته ولله الحمد طيبة. ودعا سموه الجميع إلى توخي الحيطة والتثبت في نقل المعلومات والأنباء، ليكون استخدامنا للتقنية الحديثة ومواقع التواصل الاجتماعي، لكل ما فيه خير مجتمعنا ووطننا، راجياً المولى جلت قدرته أن يديم نعمة الأمن والاستقرار والتقدم والازدهار في ربوع وطننا الغالي، وأن يشمل برعايته وعنايته قيادتنا الحكيمة وجميع المواطنين والمقيمين على هذه الأرض العزيزة، وأن يحمي الجميع من شرور المتربصين والمغرضين. وزار الفريق أول سمو الشيخ محمد بن زايد آل نهيان ولي عهد أبوظبي نائب القائد الأعلى للقوات المسلحة البارحة سهيل شاهين المرر في منزله داخل مدينة خليفة ـ أبوظبي. والتقى سموه أفراد الأسرة والأقارب والحضور، وتبادل معهم التهاني بمناسبة حلول شهر رمضان المبارك والأحاديث الودية حول ما يشكله شهر رمضان الفضيل من فرصة طيبة لتعزيز التواصل والتآلف والتراحم الذي يتحلى به مجتمع الإمارات. ودعا المولى عز وجل أن يديم الصحة والعافية على قائد المسيرة صاحب السمو الشيخ خليفة بن زايد آل نهيان رئيس الدولة، حفظه الله . وتقدم الحضور بالدعاء إلى المولى عز وجل أن يحفظ دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة، ويزيدها تقدما ورخاء، وأن يحفظ صاحب السمو الشيخ خليفة بن زايد آل نهيان رئيس الدولة ذخراً لوطنه وشعبه، ويديم عليه الصحة والعافية ليواصل مسيرة الخير والعطاء، وأن يرحم المغفور له الشيخ زايد بن سلطان آل نهيان، طيب الله ثراه، مؤسس وباني هذه الدولة وإخوانه حكام الإمارات الأوائل يرحمهم الله جميعاً. وأعرب سهيل المرر وأفراد أسرته عن شكرهم وامتنانهم لسمو ولي عهد أبوظبي على تلبيته الدعوة وزيارتهم، مرحبين وأفراد الأسرة بهذه الزيارة الكريمة التي تعبر عن عمق الروابط والتواصل بين قيادة دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة وأبناء الوطن. رافق سموه في الزيارة الفريق سمو الشيخ سيف بن زايد آل نهيان نائب رئيس مجلس الوزراء وزير الداخلية، وعبدالله مهير الكتبي، ومحمد مبارك المزروعي وكيل ديوان ولي العهد. [news_category] => home-news [news_name] => إماراتنا [news_key] => source [news_source] => وام ـ أبوظبي [news_image] => ) )

when i check the post value i got blank data ; there is any mistake in my code

Comment: you json_encode the array

Comment: no i simple post array

Comment: the above result is print_r()

Comment: no you CAN'T post array. plus your dataType: 'json' not 'html'

Answer (score 0):

instead of this

```
 var data = '<?php $details?>';
```

try

```
 var data = '<?php echo json_encode($details);?>';
```

Comment: how to get result in server page??

Comment: print_r($_POST) and you will get the result.

Comment: I USE AS var_dump(json_decode($_POST));  
exit; I GOT ERROR json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: @kavita you don't want to use json_decode, you can directly access with $_POST method as above mention.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data from php in json format:

```
echo json_encode($details);exit;
```

and use data in success by parsing it:

```
jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```